# Does REST doc have to contains all possible values of each request parameter?

Tags: java, spring, rest, documentation

When it comes to write REST doc documentations, is it good to write all possible values of each request parameter? I think it's better even though there are many other ways to get the information like source codes. But I am not sure. Is there correct answer, or it's just a matter of team policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to that question is depends on the project that you are working on. If this API will be used by many other developers and open to everyone, I think it would be better to put a few example code snippets by using a different language and explain each parameter like what is used for and the limits that should be considered. I think you don't need to put all possible combinations after simply explain each parameter itself. You may look at popular projects API documentation to get an idea; for example :

[Github API Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api)

[Twitter API Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/overview)

[Dropbox API Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation)

These documentations are giving every detail that a developer needs. If this API is only for your small team and you don't need such detailed explanations you may use Swagger like tools to easily document your API.

[Swagger](https://swagger.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the above, just wanted to add another handy thing. You might want to have Postman Collection with all the test case scenarios. This will come handy when you will want to share it with the team or QA. There is a practice to keep the Postman Collections in source control and to update them as needed.